# Firefox devtools: how to hide console from other dev tabs?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, firefox-developer-tools

When I open my Firefox 55 devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), the Console shows up under every tab. Here it's taking up the bottom 40% of the Network Monitor tab:

[image]

This can be useful if I want to see new console messages as they appear, but it's annoying when I don't need the console because it occupies the precious little space I have.

How can I toggle the visibility of the Console when other devtools tabs are in focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or use the split console button ([image: split console button]) to toggle the visibility of the console.

> You can use the console alongside other tools. While you're in another
>   tool in the Toolbox, just press Esc or press the "Toggle split
>   console" button in the Toolbar. The toolbox will now appear split,
>   with the original tool above and the web console underneath.

[Split console - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Split_console)

[All Keyboard Shortcuts - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts)